# What is the difference between executions and configurations in a maven plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

[I found this description](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Configuring_Build_Plugins) but it does not seem comprehensive.  Could someone explain in detail what is the difference between `executions` and `configurations` in a maven plugin?

Comment: You mean, aside from `execution` *has-a* `configuration`?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede These elements also live at the same height.  You can have a configuration without an execution.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

An `<execution>` causes the plugin to be executed during the maven build lifecycle, i.e. during your build. The `<configuration>` allows you to configure the plugin for how it should behave during execution. Many Maven plugins provide documentation about their configuration options, e.g. the [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html).

You can define `<configuration>`s on the `<plugin>` level or the `<execution>` level. The former is globally valid for all executions, the latter is specific to the execution.

**Example for global an execution-specific configurations:**

Suppose, you have to compile your project with Java 1.7 but you want to early adopt Java 9 [Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) features and add a `module-info.java` to your project. This Java file will not compile using source level 1.7. What you can do is define two executions of the maven-compiler-plugin, one that compiles everything except `module-info.java` with source level 1.7 and one that does only compile `module-info.java` with source level 1.9:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3</version>

  <!-- Global plugin configuration for source and target levels. -->
  <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
  </configuration>

  <executions>
    <!-- Compile all code except module-info.java with the configured source level -->
    <execution>
      <id>default-compile</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>module-info.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>

    <!-- Compile module-info.java with source level 1.9 -->
    <execution>
      <id>compile-module-info-java</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.9</source>
        <target>1.9</target>
        <includes>
          <include>module-info.java</include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Great minds think alike. :-) Amazing when it happens: two people independently and simultaneously write more or less the same thing.

Comment: great explanation thank you so much

Answer (score 16):

I think answer from @Stefan is already quite clear.  I would like to be even a bit more verbose in case it helps.

"execution" under plugin is declaring "what should be done at when".  Basically, an `execution` usually at least contains: `phase` and `goal` (I know you don't always see it in config, but conceptually they are there), which you can see it as: When the build process reached `phase`, then the `goal` action of the plugin will be executed.

Of course, you can have multiple `execution`s for a plugin, so that different/same goals can be run in different/same phases.

Then come to `configuration`.  Sometimes you need to tell the plugin extra detail on how the plugin should act on because the plugin may not be able to guess what you want to do by default.  `configuration` is doing such work.  You can refer to document of plugin's goal to see what kind of configuration they accept.

Plugin level `configuration` will be applied to all `execution`s of the plugin, while you can also define `configuration` under each `execution`, which serve as `execution`-specific configuration.  Plugin-level `configuration` + execution-level `configuration` is the "real" configuration received by an `execution`.

Answer (score 4):

A `<configuration>` section *outside* an `<execution>` block affects the plugin's behavior in general way. For instance, plugins that are either executed directly through the CLI or have a default phase that they bind to will use this type of configuration. An example of such a plugin would be the [compiler](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html%20compiler) plugin.

On the other hand, a `<configuration>` section *inside* an `<execution>` block only applies to that specific execution.

As always, a more specific configuration can override a general configuration. So if a general configuration (outside an execution block) says `<doCheck>false</doCheck>`, an execution might choose to *only* override this by doing `<doCheck>true</doCheck>`.

Another feature of general configurations is that their parameters will be inherited by all executions of that plugin.

Comment: I think that by combining all three answers (at the time of writing), it should give a pretty consistent and clear picture of how this works.