# Multiple configuration tags for maven plugins

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

According to [maven POM reference](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.0/maven-model/maven.html) , we can define multiple `<configuration>` tag for maven plugins.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId/>
            <artifactId/>
            <version/>
            <extensions/>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <id/>
                <phase/>
                <goals/>
                <inherited/>
                <configuration/>

            </execution>

        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            ...
        </dependencies>
        <goals/>
        <inherited/>
        <configuration/>
    </plugin>
```

If you can see one `<configuration>` is inside the `<execution>` tag and other outside. Let us take an example to see it more clearly :

Example :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-test</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
          </includes>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
      </includes>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>

  </plugin>
```

Consider the following surefire plugin . It has 2 `<configuration>`. One is inside the `<execution>` and other outside.

What is the difference between the two ? Please explain in general terms and not just for surefire plugin example. Is the outside something like global configuration ?

Comment: one is global configuration, the other is execution-specific configuration

Comment: @spi when does global configuration run ? If i just mention `mvn some_plugin:goal` will global config happen or execution one ?

Comment: it applies whenever nothing else overrides it. when you call a goal of a plugin (as in your exemple), it doesn't refer to any specific execution, so it will use the global configuration (but keep in mind some plugin do declare a default execution and bind it to some phase - that may interfer with configuration resolution when invoking a phase instead of a goal).

Comment: @spi Please add an answer because your comment effectively answers the question.

Comment: @JFMeier I usually dont post answers, as I don't care about reputation....

Comment: You can configure a plugin like this but in particular about surefire I would strongly recommend to read the plugin documents which things are already default and only configure what is different.

Comment: You could also refer following link. It describes detailed information around declaring `configuration` tag outside `execution` block and inside `execution` block. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908315/what-is-the-difference-between-executions-and-configurations-in-a-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is global configuration, the other is execution-specific configuration

The global applies whenever nothing else overrides it. When you call a goal of a plugin (as in your example), it doesn't refer to any specific execution, so it will use the global configuration

But keep in mind some plugins do declare a default execution and bind it to some phase - that may interfere with configuration resolution when invoking a phase instead of a goal.

Comment: Thank you. It helps the reader to see that the question is actually answered, and a "real" answer is more visible than a comment.